# How to setup authentication in React

Tags: react-native, authentication, axios, expo, bearer-token

How can I setup Authentication for a react-native expo app if am using redux for state management

Well the way the authentication flow worked was when a user enters the app for the first time and if they are not registered or logged in it they will be required to input their email to get an otp from the server and after which they now verify the otp and register too.
I used bearer token authentication the send otp request worked but the registration and confirmation of the otp by the user didn't work

Comment: Sounds like it's better to google `react-native expo authentication` and use any of article from the google's list